# Should a DTO parser/mapper wrap and rethrow domain exceptions?

Tags: java, c#, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

Let's say I have this value object:

```
public class Latitude {
    private Double value;
    public Latitude(Double value) {
        if (value < -180 || value > 180) {
            throw RuntimeException("Invalid value for latitude");
        }
        this.value = value;
    }
    public Double getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

And this DTO:

```
public class LatitudeDTO {
    private Double value;
    public Double getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

I want to create a Parser, so I can use it in the application service in this way:

```
Latitude latitude = latitudeParser.fromDTO(latitudeDTO);
```

I'm considering two option for implementing this parser. Option #1:

```
public class LatitudeParser {
    public Latitude fromDTO(LatitudeDTO latitudeDTO) throws DtoParserException {
        try {
            return new Latitude(latitudeDTO.getValue());
        } catch(RuntimeException e) {
            throw new DtoParserException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Option #2:

```
public class LatitudeParser {
    public Latitude fromDTO(LatitudeDTO latitudeDTO) throws DtoParserException {
        if (value < -180 || value > 180) {
            throw DtoParserException("Invalid value for latitude");
        }
        return new Latitude(latitudeDTO.getValue());
    }
}
```

In both cases, DtoParserException is later mapped to 400 Bad Request, when it reaches the presentation layer.

Now, for me option #1 is better, because there's no repetition of the validation rule. However, I've heard that everything that is sent to the domain must be validated before and in this sense the exceptions thrown by the domain layer point out a bug in the application layer code. In this case I shoudn't use domain exceptions to inform the user of my application that the data inputted is invalid.

So, should the parser make its own validations or use the domain validation? It seems so weird to just replicate the validation in the parser.

Comment: First of all, if you are implementing in C# I recommend you to use AutoMapper to map objects. In my opinion a mapper should just map objects, no more and no less. Therefore the exception should not be thrown in the mapper. If the user can input the value you should validate the users input in the UI first. In the second step you should validate it in the backends application layer, maybe you are able to use property attributes in your DTO for validation?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I'm not considering using auto mappers. About the mapper responsability, I can see how a "mapper" only maps, that's why I called it a parser instead, as a parser operation may be expected to fail if the data isn't valid. Now, the parser is part of the application layer, so I think you are suggesting Option #2, right? I mean, since you recommended doing it in the application layer.

Comment: Yes, if the error needs to get thrown while parsing I would go with option 2. But if you leave the check in constructor of the `Latitude` class as well, I would outsource the logic check into a separate place to avoid code dublication.

Answer (score 0):

> everything that is sent to the domain must be validated before

I would personally rephrase this to "Everything that makes it into the domain layer is valid". I'm saying this because one reason to use value objects as parameters into the domain layer is that it removes the need for format validation logic in the domain layer. Compare the following to signatures:

```
public void RegisterUser(string firstName, string lastName, string phoneNumber, string email)
```

vs

```
public void RegisterUser(FullName name, PhoneNumber phoneNumber, Email email)
```

In the second scenario, you can be certain that all parameters are non null and with correctly formatted data.

So, when it says that "must be validated before", in this case, the constructor of the value object is already "before" getting into the business logic layer.

What I would say is that `RuntimeException` is not a very good name for that exception. Note that exceptions are part of the "Contract" of a class. In the case of the value object, the constructor, the public properties and the exceptions are part of its contract, so you'd probably have something like `InvalidCoordinatesException` or similar.

The reason I'm saying this is that the DTO parser logic probably belongs to the same layer that currently handles your `DtoParserException`, so maybe you don't need to translate the exception at all and you directly can handle the InvalidCoordinatesException (or a base ValueObjectValidationException). But that's for your consideration.

Comment: But how would I be able to tell who's responsible for the invalid data? If I just throw the InvalidCoordinatesException, how would I be able to tell it was the user who sent invalid data and eventually convert that to a 400 bad request at the presentation layer?

Comment: Not sure if I get your question. You'll know who's responsible for the error depending one where you are calling these methods. For example, if you have an API for your front end and an API for 3rd party integrations and they both call a ParseCoordinates() method, the one that passes the wrong coordinates will get the exception.

Comment: You're correct. I'm sorry, I was with a specific setting in mind, where the exception are not catched in the code, but rather handled in a exception handler that belongs to the presentation layer (it is also responsible for mapping the exception to http status code). In this case, InvalidCoordinatesException wouldn't be enough to know which status code map to. While DtoParserException, or better, InputDtoParserException could be mapped to a 400.

Comment: But in the setting where all the exception are checked, your solution makes more sense, as the exception is part of the contract as you said.

Comment: But one more question, in your catch for the InvalidCoordinatesException exception, would you map it to another exception that will be handled by the presentation layer?